# How do I recreate EFI system partition on dual boot macOS and Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I'm happy to be here with you expert guys in Linux Ubuntu!

Making opportunity to ask for help here:

1. I recently managed to install Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a classic Macpro 2010 dual processor.
2. I had my existing macOS Mojave SSD in bay 1, installed Open Core because I need to have dual boot. I created Ubuntu USB installer by using standard process with ISO and Balena Etcher.
3. I installed the Ubuntu on separated SSD in bay 2. Installation process was smooth and dual boot are working by choosing OS from boot picker.
4. After about a week enjoying Ubuntu , I wanted to add my RAM to 96GB. Unfortunately the new additional 2 RAM sticks are not matched, causing my machin unable to boot up, the chime sounded, but boot picker gone and my GPU RX580 kept spinning, but no show on screen, back screen!
5. I put back my original RAM, issue remained the same. I reset NVRAM 3 times, it didn't work.
6. I took out the 2 SSDs, mounted my native macOS High Sierra on bay 1, the did NVRAM reset once again and it booted up .
7. After that I put back my Mojave SSD on bay 2. Set Startup disk to Mojave from Higher Sierra system. It worked.
8. I put Ubuntu SSD back on bay 3, by using Clover Configurator, I saw there's no more EFI partition shown on my Ubuntu SSD, my goodness!!

Question:
What is the proper way now to recreate EFI system partition for my Ubuntu SSD without having to reinstall from beginning, becuawe I setup the Ubuntu nicely with many wonderful apps, customization, etc.

I'm looking forward to getting right solution to make my Ubuntu alive again!

Thank you in advance.